# Developing reminder application in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, alarmmanager, android-notifications, reminders

I'm creating a reminder application that will show notifications on scheduled time, I'll be storing reminder related data in a database and created the working database and content provider for it, initially I thought of creating an alarm whenever user creates a new reminder, but now I'm not able to fire the notification whenever the alarm triggers, and don't know how can I retrieve the reminder related info from the database, and for repeating reminders like daily or weekly I want to reschedule the same alarm after it triggers as the android developer docs suggested so, but don't have the exact idea of it. Please guide me through this which approach will be better and is there any other better way to do it, and any working demo will be very helpful.

Comment: Please show the SO community the code you're currently using. That will make it much easier for people to offer help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it is quite a few questions bundled up into one. I would suggest searching for each individual piece as all of the answers to your questions are on this site.

In any case, I copied over an answer on how to set a repeating alarm

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) ct.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);         
Intent intent1 = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, Alarm.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ct, 0,intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

Date curr=new Date();
curr.setHours(h);
curr.setMinutes(m);
c.setTime(curr);
c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

With this code an intent will be fired every day that calls Alarm.class. It is up to you to figure out if you need a service, intent, or anything else as Alarm.class, as it is unclear what the alarm needs to do based on your description.

Comment: yeah, you're right I just tried to put different questions in a single one and made the mess, sorry for that, I don't have any problem with this block of code I just want to show the reminder title and it's description in the notification, and not sure about how to do it, I tried using cursorloader to retrieve the data from database and then issue a notification using alarm manager but it isn't working.